# Special Characters in wordpress page not working with src attribute, when working locally

Tags: php, html, wordpress, xampp, special-characters

I have a local version (using Xampp) of a live page and if I call to:

```
<img src="/imagelocation/españa.jpg">
```

I get this error

> GET /imagelocation/espa%CC%83a.jpg 404 (Not Found)

The character works fine in **p** or **h** tags, the live site works fine and it also works fine locally in other computers so I guess it has to be some configuration in this specific computer, but I really don't know where to look for it.

Answer (score 0):

find this two tags and comment this in wp-config file

```
   define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
   define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

to

```
  // define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
  //define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```